# How to test a string which is a number for >INT_MAX or <INT_MIN on a 32bit µC?

Tags: c, int, max

A customer text based protocol is used and it allows to set int32 values for some specific parameters by sending them e.g. from PC to a 32bit µC. I need to check if the received parameter is in range [INT_MIN, INT_MAX]. I need to generate a failure if the number is outside of this range.
Simply casting to int and compare that with [INT_MIN, INT_MAX] would fail.

My current idea is: 
1. casting the string to number, 
2. casting the number to string, 
3. compare the received and casted string from 2. ,

If both equal the number in the string should be a valid int32 value.

Are there any other suggetions or ideas?
Thx

Comment: Check the string length (say 11) to see if it can be read into a 64-bit variable. If longer: fail. Read into a 64-bit variable and check the range. Convert to `int`.

Comment: If I didn't have my own integer parsing function, I think I'd use `strtol` with proper error checking and then check if the resulting `long` fits into an `int`.

Comment: @PSkocik That only works if `long` is larger than `int`, which it isn't on Windows or 32-bit Linux (along with a lot of other platforms).

Comment: @AndrewHenle If it isn't, it continues to work, except the second part, i.e., checking whether the result fits into an `int`, becomes a no-op (always fits).

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's unfortunate that `sscanf` isn't guaranteed to achieve this in one step.

Comment: @PSkocik Yeah, that would be another `*scanf()` deficiency.

Answer (score 2):

> How to test a string which is a number for `>INT_MAX` or `<INT_MIN` ...
>
> check if the received parameter is in range [INT_MIN, INT_MAX]

"casting the string to number," and "casting the number to string," will not work as an `int` test.  Code needs to *convert*.

[`long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) readily does this. [@PSkocik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869705/how-to-test-a-string-which-is-a-number-for-int-max-or-int-min-on-a-32bit-%c2%b5c/60873655#comment107694545_60869705)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool test_int(const char *s, int *int_result) {
  char *endptr;   // Location where conversion stopped
  errno = 0;      // Need to clear, to test for overflow later
  long n = strtol(s, &endptr, 0);
  if (errno == ERANGE) {
    return false; // Outside long range
  }

  // In case int is narrower than long
  #if LONG_MIN < INT_MIN || LONG_MAX > INT_MAX
  if (n < INT_MIN || n > INT_MAX) {
      return false; // Outside int range
  }
  #endif

  if (s == endptr) {
    return false; // No conversion
  }
  
  // Perhaps allow trailing white-space?
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }

  if (*endptr != '\0') {
    return false; // Extra junk at the end
  }

  *int_result = (int) n;
  return true;
}
```

---

As part of a protocol parser, with various ranged integers, consider a general purpose *signed* test:

```
bool test_integer(const char *s, intmax_t *integer, intmax_t mn, intmax_t mx) {
  char *endptr; 
  errno = 0;
  *integer = strtoimax(s, &endptr, 0);
  if (errno == ERANGE || *integer < mn || *integer > mx) {
    *integer = (*integer < mn) ? mn : mx;
    errno == ERANGE;
    return false; // Outside intmax_t range
  }

  while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }

  if (s == endptr || *endptr != '\0') {
    return false; // No conversion or junk at end
  }
  
  return true;
}

// Sample usage for int
intmax_t im;
if (test_integer(s, &im, INT_MIN, INT_MAX))  {
  int i = (int) im;
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed number of compile-time numbers this check can be done efficiently directly on the string. More so, given that you can directly tell by the first character whether or not it is negative or not.

After you branch into checking for MAX_INT or MIN_INT, two numbers you can convert to a string `cmp` either at design time or **once** at runtime, you can easily do the following:

1. Check if the length of the input exceeds the length of `cmp` ->fail
2. If it is shorter ->pass
3. If it is equal compare both strings component wise while the characters match. The first character in the input string that compares strictly greater than cmp results in a ->fail
4. Otherwise the input is fine and you can convert it.

Yes, this adds an additional loop and n+1 branches in the worst case you if you validate the string in this pass, you can omit all branches in the conversion step, so you will only have to pay **one** additional branch.